# 'unfocus' causes TextField to be cleared

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am trying to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus();` to unfocus from a textfield, but once I do it, the field gets cleared out. I am using a `GestureDetector` on a `ListView.builder` to detect either a `onTap` or `onVerticalDragDown` and then call `WidgetsBinding.instance.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`.

I tried defining a TextEdittingController but the same result. I also tried to just hide the keyboard with `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');` but also didn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the full condensed code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you're using, you can use a **GestureDetector**, over the parent of your **TextFeild**, to remove the Focus from the TextField like this:

```
 GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
    child: Container(
        child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'TextField',
            ),
       )
    ...
```